# Android: Storage Access Framework - Just need to copy a file to extSD

Tags: android, xamarin, android-permissions, android-external-storage

Existing Xamarin Forms app on Android.
New feature request from the bosses: To copy some updated documents from a USB FlashDrive to a known directory on the extSD already in the tablet.

Seems like that shouldn't require a PhD.  Everything we've done to date has been on the internal storage so typical System.IO calls work fine.  But Android has this whole Storage Access Framework stuff in place for things like the external SD, or Google Drive or where ever.

Every question and tutorial I see are all for the same thing: How to open a document browser to the SD card, or how to create a new CREATE DOCUMENT INTENT.

I'm not looking to do any of that.  Don't need a UI.  Not making a new text file from scratch.

I just want to copy a file from the flashdrive to the extSD. Everything else is in place to do this to internal storage.  Easy-Peezy.
Its a single line when copying from the flashdrive to the internal SD.

```
FileInfo.CopyTo(targetAddress, true);
```

How do I copy a file to the extSD?  Do I really need 200 lines of overhead making a DOCUMENTPROVIDER, and CONTRACT and 20 other things just to copy a file?  All I get is "ACCESS TO extSD 1234-5678 is denied".  Seems like it should be fairly simple to get permission to the card then just copy a file or make a new folder.  But I swear everything I read for SAF makes it sound like you have to make 10 classes and a manager for them all first.

Anyone got a simple example of the minimalist way to get write permission to the extSD and copy from A to B?

Comment: To access SD card directly in android 10 your app needs to be an [external storage manager](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).

Comment: "Do I really need 200 lines of overhead [...]" - yes. Welcome to the wonderful world of Android.

Comment: @pawel First: Thanks for that amazing fast response.
Yeah I saw that article before. We have the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set in manifest.

I did get hung up on this, previously;

> Use the ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION intent action to direct users to a system settings page where they can enable the following option for your app: Allow access to manage all files.

as I can't find an example of how they're doing that, and can't reverse-engineer a C# that seems to do the same thing or recognize that enum.

Comment: Should mention - Not in Android 10 yet.  Android 8 & 9 tablets.  With an app that is still targeting 6.  Still, same permissions for anything above 4.4 (KitKat+) if I am reading things right.

Answer (score 0):

If it is copying only one file them its pretty simple. Let the user select the fle with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. You get an uri for the file. Now let the user create a file at the right place using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. You got another uri. Now open an InputStream and an OutputStream for those uries. Then read bytes from input and write to output. Less then 200 lines ;-)

Comment: Appreciate that - but that's not the workflow.  This is a recursive file copy of updated data, about 16,000 documents in 800 folders.  No UI.  
Stick the USB stick in, detect prorammacitally, update automatically, give the user a popup telling them copy in progress, copy done, remove USB.

Not done with it yet - but it turns out that its a whole lot simpler than all the articles by doing a byte copy through a file stream.  Once the routine is finished and armor plated for robustness I'll post it.

Comment: Then let the user choose the source and destination directory using twice ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Then copy source tree to destination tree.

Comment: You're missing the part about "no let the user pick anything".  But like I said above, I think this has been resolved avoiding all of the SAF nonsense, but doing a java-level byte array copy.  Its a 10 line loop instead of all that other insanity.